# How to encrypt drush backups with gnupg

Tags: drush, cron

I am trying to set up a cron job that automatically backups up a Drupal site using drush but then encrypts that file. I would like to accomplish this using a single command but am not sure how to go about it.

Here is the command that does the backup and logs any messages (this works):

```
drush @mysite archive-dump --destination="/home/drush-backups/archive-dump/mysite.$(date +\%F_\%H-\%M-\%S).tar.gz" &>> /var/log/mysites/$(hostname -s)/drush-cron.log
```

However when I try this:

```
drush @mysite archive-dump --destination="/home/drush-backups/archive-dump/mysite.$(date +\%F_\%H-\%M-\%S).tar.gz" | gpg -e -r mypublickey &>> /var/log/mysites/$(hostname -s)/drush-cron.log
```

It does not work. Any ideas where I am going wrong? What is the correct command?

Thanks.

Comment: Does not work. Are there errors? Is gpg a reachable command by the user trying to execute it? What happens when you run this from command line as the apache user? Or the user executing it?

Comment: You're piping the output of the drush command into gpg - you need to pipe the contents of the _file_ that the command creates, probably as a 2nd statement altogether. Maybe drush has an option to return the file stream instead, but if not just use a 2nd statement and use gpg with the file path option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're piping the output of the Drush command to `gpg`, but it's expecting a file path.

By default the output will not be something that `gpg` can use, but `archive-dump` has a handy `--pipe` option which will print just the path to the output file; `gpg` can use that:

```
drush @mysite archive-dump --pipe --destination="/home/drush-backups/archive-dump/mysite.$(date +\%F_\%H-\%M-\%S).tar.gz" | gpg -e -r mypublickey &>> /var/log/mysites/$(hostname -s)/drush-cron.log
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured that I was missing something really trivial.